# Add line to XML using attribute as identifier

Tags: java, android, xml

My `XML` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test1>
<task uuid="92F7F685-C370-4E55-9026-020E3CDCEDE0" status="1000">
    <task_status>200</task_status>    
</task>
<task uuid="92F7F685-C370-4E55-9026-020E3CDCEDE0" status="
    <task_status>200</task_status>
</task>
</Test1>
```

This file is stored in the private app directory. I just want to edit this file and store it in it's "newer" version in the same directory.

I have this method to write and read the XML files:

```
private void writeToFile(String data, String fileName) {
    try {
        String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, UTF8), BUFFER_SIZE);
        bufferedWriter.write(data);
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("writeToFile: ", "Datei-Erstellung fehlgeschlagen: " + e.toString());
    }
}

//Datei lesen von Datei im privatem App-Verzeichnis
private String readFromFile(String fileName) {
    String ret = "";
    String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(fileName);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, UTF8), BUFFER_SIZE);
            String receiveString;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("readFromFile: ", "Datei nicht gefunden: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("readFromFile: ", "Kann Datei nicht lesen: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

How can I add a new tag like `<task_note>`? I want to put it in the right task, so I have to use the `uuid` attribute to identify where I have to put the tag.

The `XmlPullParser` is just for reading as I know, so this doesn't help.

So, how can I do this then?

EDIT:

I get this Error:

```
  07-28 11:16:22.676  17703-17703/de.exampleapp W/System.err﹕ javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 000273E060E87000C0001323FA21427120150602153306.kx_task
07-28 11:16:22.676  17703-17703/de.exampleapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:481)
07-28 11:16:22.676  17703-17703/de.example.app W/System.err﹕ at de.example.app.TasksList.onActivityResult(TasksList.java:141)
```

I get this here:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(filename);

            String uuid = taskItems.get(position).get("uuid");
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            try {
                Node taskNode = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//task[@uuid='" + uuid + "']", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE);
                Document document = taskNode.getOwnerDocument();
                //Füge neue Zeile ein
                Node noteNode = document.createElement("task_note");
                noteNode.setTextContent(taskItems.get(position).get("task_note"));
                taskNode.appendChild(noteNode);
                //Speichere Datei
                Source input = new DOMSource(document);
                Result output = new StreamResult(new File(filename));
                TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(input, output);
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`XPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) , and other Java XML standard libraries within Android:

```
    // Read file
    InputSource inputStream = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(inputFileName));

    // Find the task node
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Node taskNode = (Node)xpath.evaluate("//task[uuid='92F7F685-C370-4E55-9026-020E3CDCEDE0']", inputStream,
            XPathConstants.NODE);
    Document document = taskNode.getOwnerDocument();
    // Insert a new node
    Node noteNode = document.createElement("task_note");
    noteNode.setTextContent("this is a note");
    taskNode.appendChild(noteNode);

    // Save file
    Source input = new DOMSource(document);
    Result output = new StreamResult(new File(outputFileName));
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(input, output);
```

Comment: I get every time a XPathExpressionException When i use this expression... do you know why?

Comment: No - please post the details of the exception.

Comment: Sorry, my `InputSource inputStream = new InputSource(inputFileName);` is wrong. You should use another constructor. I'll update my answer.

Comment: okay now i know what's the problem... it couldn't find the file... Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are treating your XML data as simple text files. This is not a good idea. XML is a data format that only happens to be text-based - that's like reading a dictionary from start to the end... Yes, it's a book, technically, so you could do that, but not what's it normally used for. Same with XML, you CAN read it as a simple text file, but normally you want to actually parse the data contained in this text, manipulate this data and then serialize the XML again.

So you should read it via one of the many possibilities to handle XML out there, for example via [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) ( using the Schema you hopefully have) or a simple [DOMParser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html). But of course there are many other ways out there to do it...

Comment: So is it a besser idea to use JSON instead of XML? Are there more tools for handling JSON than with XML?

Comment: Not really. It simply depends on what you want to do in the end. For example, if you want your data to be readable by JavaScript easily, for example when writing some web application, then JSON would be an obivious choice. But XML is not "wrong" in any absolute kind of way. In any way, you will need some specific method to modify it, but that is true for both XML and JSON.